# Where does model manipulation logic go in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm building an application that fetches calendar data via an AJAX call at the $rootScope. I use this object in various controllers, and I need to be able to parse it appropriately, as there are various objects nested within it. Where should I store the logic to parse it? I've had it in the root controller as $rootScope functions, but I feel like this is the use case for a factory. However, it doesn't seem like I can (nor does it feel like it would it be a good idea to) access the factory methods from templates.

At the moment I have the following factory:

```
angular.module('services',[]).
factory('dataManipulation', function(){
    return{
        getPerson: function(peopleObj, userID){
            //Since each user has a unique ID, this returns an array with one element,
            // so to simplify the view code, there's a [0] at the end
            var person= peopleObj.filter(function(element, index, array) {
                if (array[index].cwid == userID) {
                    return true;
                }
            })[0];
            return person;
        }
    };
});
```

And the following in my controller:

```
angular.module('app.controllers',[]).
controller('rootCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$http', 'dataManipulation',
    function($rootScope, $http, dataManipulation) {
        $rootScope.getPerson = function(peopleObj, userID){
            return dataManipulation.getPerson(peopleObj, userID);
        }
    }
]);
```

And it works, but I'm just not sure if I'm following best practices.

So, should these functions to parse the model be in the rootScope or somewhere else?

Comment: Put it in a service module, and inject that module into your controllers.

Comment: I would build a "Person" factory.
From your controller you could then call Person.get(someIdentifier) which would load the same Person object with data or return a seperate instance model. 
Take a look at Angular resources. I believe they will illustrate the concept a little bit better for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post is somewhat confusing (you need to parse an object? :s) but
I would use a service or provider or factory (implementory variations of the same thing) to achieve what you are describing.
This would allow you avoid the use of $rootScope entirely and inject your service / factory into the controllers where their use is required.

$scope essentially is your model (or rather a storage device for your model, there are dangers associated with storing data directly against $scope i.e $scope.x = 1) in the context of your Angular application, and $rootScope its 'global' parent that is used primarily for managing scopes internally (as I understand, I may be wrong and will try to confirm this) and emitting events at a global scope, but can be used quite conveniently to store data - though this should be avoided where possible. 
IMO the idea is to deliver your model to your Angular app in as near to a usable state as possible so that the only manipulation required to the model within the Angular app is purely presentational.

Comment: I've added the code in the question since you posted this. Are you basically saying that what I'm doing in the second code block is right, but I should just do that in each controller that needs to get data from the model?

Comment: I use services, factories and providers for AJAX work where Angulars $resources will not suffice. 
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource
Try to emulate the functionality of a $resource and you will be on the right track in terms of good practices (in my opinion. this really is subjective)